# Calculate trailing variance in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, variance

I have a dataframe which looks as follows:

```
     | symbol |    date    |  close   
 ----|--------|------------|---------- 
   0 | APX    | 5/31/2017  |     4.04 
   1 | APX    | 6/30/2017  |      5.4 
   2 | APX    | 7/31/2017  |     4.15 
   3 | APX    | 8/31/2017  |     9.95 
   4 | APX    | 9/30/2017  |     10.3 
   5 | APX    | 10/31/2017 |     5.58 
   6 | APX    | 11/30/2017 |     8.47 
   7 | APX    | 12/31/2017 |    15.66 
   8 | APX    | 1/31/2018  |    10.55 
   9 | APX    | 2/28/2018  |      9.8 
  10 | APX    | 3/31/2018  |     7.43 
  11 | APX    | 4/30/2018  |     8.93 
  12 | APX    | 5/31/2018  |     7.61 
  13 | APX    | 6/30/2018  |     7.79 
  14 | AURA   | 1/31/2018  | 0.221382 
  15 | AURA   | 2/28/2018  | 0.222236 
  16 | AURA   | 3/31/2018  | 0.075488 
  17 | AURA   | 4/30/2018  | 0.180699 
  18 | AURA   | 5/31/2018  | 0.220009 
  19 | AURA   | 6/30/2018  | 0.199029 
  20 | BASH   | 11/30/2016 | 0.000447 
  21 | BASH   | 12/31/2016 | 0.000376 
  22 | BASH   | 1/31/2017  | 0.000452 
  23 | BASH   | 2/28/2017  | 0.000414 
  24 | BASH   | 3/31/2017  |  0.00045 
  25 | BASH   | 4/30/2017  | 0.000754 
  26 | BASH   | 5/31/2017  | 0.009115 
  27 | BASH   | 6/30/2017  |  0.03419 
  28 | BASH   | 7/31/2017  | 0.014037 
  29 | BASH   | 8/31/2017  | 0.009117 
  30 | BASH   | 9/30/2017  | 0.002333 
  31 | BASH   | 10/31/2017 |  0.00258 
  32 | BASH   | 11/30/2017 | 0.003415 
  33 | BASH   | 12/31/2017 | 0.003756 
  34 | BASH   | 1/31/2018  | 0.005454 
  35 | BASH   | 2/28/2018  | 0.006186 
  36 | BASH   | 3/31/2018  | 0.004155 
  37 | BASH   | 4/30/2018  | 0.005078 
  38 | BASH   | 5/31/2018  | 0.003696 
  39 | BASH   | 6/30/2018  | 0.003442
```

I would like to calculate 6-month trailing variance for each symbol and add this as a new column in to the dataframe. The variance should be calculated based on the value in the `close` column.

So for example, for APX there are 14 observations, so the first variance should be calculated based on the values 4.04, 5.4, 4.15, 9.95, 10.3 and 5.58.

The next variance should be calculated based on 5.4, 4.15, 9.95, 10.3, 5.58 and 8.47, etc.

I assume I need to use the `df.var` function to calculate the variance but how do I tell calculate this on a trailing 6-month basis for each symbol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupby` and `rolling(6)` together with `var()` to get the rolling variance for the previous 6 observations in the data separated for each group. Setting `min_periods` to 6 will force the function to use at least 6 values for the calculation, without setting this a lower number of observations will be used for the first 5 results.

```
df['trailing_var'] = df.groupby('symbol')['close'].rolling(6, min_periods=6).var().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Result:

```
  symbol          date       close    trailing_var
0    APX     5/31/2017    4.040000             NaN
1    APX     6/30/2017    5.400000             NaN
2    APX     7/31/2017    4.150000             NaN
3    APX     8/31/2017    9.950000             NaN
4    APX     9/30/2017    10.30000             NaN
5    APX    10/31/2017    5.580000    7.988720e+00
6    APX    11/30/2017    8.470000    6.776377e+00
7    APX    12/31/2017    15.66000    1.648918e+01
8    APX     1/31/2018    10.55000    1.085291e+01
9    APX     2/28/2018    9.800000    1.086476e+01
10   APX     3/31/2018    7.430000    1.196206e+01
11   APX     4/30/2018    8.930000    8.470240e+00
12   APX     5/31/2018    7.610000    9.167987e+00
13   APX     6/30/2018    7.790000    1.662630e+00
14   AURA    1/31/2018    0.221382             NaN
15   AURA    2/28/2018    0.222236             NaN
16   AURA    3/31/2018    0.075488             NaN
17   AURA    4/30/2018    0.180699             NaN
18   AURA    5/31/2018    0.220009             NaN
19   AURA    6/30/2018    0.199029    3.226191e-03
20   BASH   11/30/2016    0.000447             NaN
21   BASH   12/31/2016    0.000376             NaN
22   BASH    1/31/2017    0.000452             NaN
23   BASH    2/28/2017    0.000414             NaN
24   BASH    3/31/2017    0.000450             NaN
25   BASH    4/30/2017    0.000754    1.859857e-08
26   BASH    5/31/2017    0.009115    1.241904e-05
27   BASH    6/30/2017    0.034190    1.820075e-04
28   BASH    7/31/2017    0.014037    1.741278e-04
29   BASH    8/31/2017    0.009117    1.539841e-04
30   BASH    9/30/2017    0.002333    1.464200e-04
31   BASH   10/31/2017    0.002580    1.390604e-04
32   BASH   11/30/2017    0.003415    1.508145e-04
33   BASH   12/31/2017    0.003756    2.221467e-05
34   BASH    1/31/2018    0.005454    6.464003e-06
35   BASH    2/28/2018    0.006186    2.415413e-06
36   BASH    3/31/2018    0.004155    1.787309e-06
37   BASH    4/30/2018    0.005078    1.150985e-06
38   BASH    5/31/2018    0.003696    1.022634e-06
39   BASH    6/30/2018    0.003442    1.160249e-06
```